# My cousin's odd farm

Tags: word, wordplay

I recently went to visit my cousin, who runs a farm. But when I got there, things were a bit, well... odd:

- His 10 horses had 24 legs, yet they could all walk normally.
- For his 30 workers he had 6 teaspoons, yet everyone had at least 1 each.
- He sent his workers out fishing with tentacle boxes, yet they each caught a lot of fish.

**How is this possible?**

<sub>Disclaimer: A friend of mine told me the first one, but I don't know where he got it from. I don't claim it as my own, but I claim the other two.</sub>

Comment: "tentacle boxes" ? boxes containing tentacles?

Comment: @lois6b, I know. Strange isn't it? Boxes made out of tentacles.

Comment: [word]: *"A puzzle whose answer will be a word or a set of words but not a phrase, sentence or sentences."* - The answer is clearly https://i.stack.imgur.com/459U4.jpg .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Final answer:**

For the 1st one:

> One thing that comes to my mind is that the horses had **twenty forelegs**. And 20 rear ones. Or whatever they are called...

For the 2nd one:

> **Six teaspons** = **sixty spoons** which is enough for 30 workers

The 3rd one is

> **Ten tackle boxes**, which are boxes used for fishing.

Comment: On the right track. Surely you can get the rest now.

Comment: And the first? It should be easy now.

Comment: Yep! You got them all.

Comment: @lois6b Thanks for edit - forgot it.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Thanks for the puzzle - always pleasure to solve these ones :)

Comment: no problem  ^^ nice answer. are you native english speaker? the "twenty forelegs" would be impossible for me

Comment: @lois6b I'm not native english speaker, but I started to learn the language about 20 years ago...

Comment: I see... that helps xD 5 years for me ( not counting highschool english classes as here the level is **too low**)

Answer (score 0):

For the first one:

> There are six adult horses (6 x 4 = 24 legs) out of which 4 horses are pregnant, making a total of 10 horses.

For the third one:

> Can a tentacle box refer to a box jellyfish?

Comment: nope. Not even close

Comment: the first one is more [tag:lateral-thinking] than [tag:wordplay]

Comment: Nice thinking anyway.